# Calculate the number of posting entries using zipf approximation

Tags: information-retrieval, zipf

Given 100 million documents containing 9 million terms, how do you calculate the total posting entries for this using a simple zipf approximation?

**My approach:**

Zipf approximation:

[image]

substituting in the formula we get probabilities as (N = 9,000,000):

```
word1 -> 1/16
word2 -> 1/(2*16)
...
wordN -> 1/(N*16), where N = 9,000,000
```

But now how do I proceed? Do I assume all words will be distributed equally throughout the documents? Total word count is also unknown, so the probabilities also do not help in anyway.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is 9 million the number of unique terms (vocab size)?

Comment: nothing else is specified, so i assumed its the vocab size. But idk, if u think taking it as the total count helps, then take it.